# PHP & MYSQL: Get all columns, select * from row and json encode the results

Tags: php, mysql, json, printing, encode

I am trying to fetch an array from a mysql and print each column with its value.

This is what I have so far:

**Get all columns:**

```
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM user_settings";
$resultx = mysql_query($query);$temp=0;$p = array();


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    $p[$temp] = $row["Field"];$temp++;
}
```

**Foreach column name fetch data where user id = $SESSION['id']**

```
foreach ($p as $f) {

        $json = array();
        $newquery = "SELECT * FROM user_settings WHERE uid = '" . $_SESSION['id'] ."'";
        $newresult = mysql_query($newquery);


        while($newrow = mysql_fetch_array($newresult)) {
                $json[$f] = $newrow[$f];
        }

        print json_encode($json);


    }
```

This works just fine. The problem is that the array printed is as such:

```
{"column1":"data"}{"column2":"data"}{"column3":"data"}
```

Instead **I would like the json encode to print**:

```
[{"column1":"data","column2":"data","column3":"data"}}
```

Comment: Why are you getting the columns and then querying the same table for all columns anyway? But on an unrelated note try moving the print to outside of the foreach loop

Comment: Because I am learning php. I am not sure how else I would do this. Could you please advise?

Comment: @DavidJones If i move the print outside the foreach loop I only get: {"column3":"data"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all of this because it is redundant.

```
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM user_settings";
$resultx = mysql_query($query);$temp=0;$p = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultx)) {
    $p[$temp] = $row["Field"];$temp++;
}
```

Also remove the foreach loop so we are only left with the query and while loop for that query.

```
$json = array();
$newquery = "SELECT * FROM user_settings WHERE uid = '" . $_SESSION['id'] ."'";
$newresult = mysql_query($newquery);

print json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($newresult));
```

This should make the json_encode() function encode a multidimensional array of results.

Also try removing the mysql_* functions and using mysqli_* functions or a PDO because the mysql_* functions are depreciated.

Comment: why do you need a loop. i doubt that you ever have 2 users with the same id, so userid is unique.

Comment: I get this:
[{"0":"data1","column1":"data1","1":"data2","column2":"data2","2":"data3","column3":"data3"]

Comment: It also prints the number of each column with its value?

Comment: @jQuerybeast I think you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysqk_fetch_array (I haven't used these functions for years!)

Comment: @DavidJones nope he does not, the 0 is from that `$json[]`

Comment: @Marius.C Yeh your correct that is one thing, but doesnt mysql_fetch_array return both numeric keys and the column names? The question says he just wants column names :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  $newquery = "SELECT * FROM user_settings WHERE uid = '" . $_SESSION['id'] ."'";
  $newresult = mysql_query($newquery);

  print json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($newresult));
```

I don't think you need the rest.